# Wubi: "global name 'sig' is not defined"

Tags: kubuntu, wubi

I am trying to install Kubuntu 14.04 x64 using the Wubi provided in the ISO file mounted using Daemon Tools, from Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

I'm getting this error message:

[image]

when I am at the stage:

[image]

after launching the installation with these parameters:

[image]

Why?

---

Last lines of `C:\Users\francky\AppData\Local\Temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log`:

```
[...]
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished uncompress_target_dir
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_uninstaller...
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying uninstaller J:\wubi.exe -> D:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi UninstallString D:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi InstallationDir D:\ubuntu
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayName Kubuntu
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayIcon D:\ubuntu\Kubuntu.ico
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayVersion 14.04-rev286
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi Publisher Kubuntu
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi URLInfoAbout http://www.kubuntu.org
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi HelpLink http://www.ubuntu.com/support
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_uninstaller
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running copy_installation_files...
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\francky\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5D7F.tmp\data\custom-installation -> D:\ubuntu\install\custom-installation
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\francky\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5D7F.tmp\winboot -> D:\ubuntu\winboot
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\francky\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5D7F.tmp\data\images\Kubuntu.ico -> D:\ubuntu\Kubuntu.ico
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished copy_installation_files
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running get_iso...
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Could not find any ISO or CD, downloading one now
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_metalink
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running get_metalink...
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/kubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink > D:\ubuntu\install
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=D:\ubuntu\install\kubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink, url=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/kubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink, basename=kubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink, length=1047, text=None
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 1047 bytes)
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/MD5SUMS-metalink > D:\ubuntu\install
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=D:\ubuntu\install\MD5SUMS-metalink, url=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/MD5SUMS-metalink, basename=MD5SUMS-metalink, length=576, text=None
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 576 bytes)
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg > D:\ubuntu\install
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=D:\ubuntu\install\MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg, url=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04/release/MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg, basename=MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg, length=933, text=None
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 933 bytes)
11-14 15:34 ERROR  TaskList: global name 'sig' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 458, in get_metalink
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 270, in check_metalink
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\signature.py", line 41, in verify_gpg_signature
  File "\lib\openpgp\sap\api.py", line 1202, in verify_str
  File "\lib\openpgp\sap\api.py", line 1100, in verify_msg
  File "\lib\openpgp\sap\crypto.py", line 445, in verify
  File "\lib\openpgp\sap\crypto.py", line 174, in hash_context
NameError: global name 'sig' is not defined
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
11-14 15:34 ERROR  TaskList: Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 595, in get_iso
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 406, in download_iso
Exception: Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO
11-14 15:34 ERROR  root: global name 'sig' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 458, in get_metalink
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 270, in check_metalink
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\signature.py", line 41, in verify_gpg_signature
  File "\lib\openpgp\sap\api.py", line 1202, in verify_str
  File "\lib\openpgp\sap\api.py", line 1100, in verify_msg
  File "\lib\openpgp\sap\crypto.py", line 445, in verify
  File "\lib\openpgp\sap\crypto.py", line 174, in hash_context
NameError: global name 'sig' is not defined
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
11-14 15:34 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
```

I have the same issue when using `wubi1510r298.exe` from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uqomp8l1frcd1y/AAAhSCimTaYE-94egbmc1X_na?dl=0, on two different computers.

I also have the same issue when trying to install Ubuntu instead of Kubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

The hash algorithm for gpg signatures has changed from sha1 to sha512 and sha512 is not supported by the used Wubi module.

I uploaded a patch to [launchpad.net](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~hakuna-matata/wubi/openpgp/revision/299) (source code)

The patch still does not provide sha512 support but it provides a better error handling. So it writes the following messages to the log...

```
WARNING saplog: A signature from ID:'46181433FBB75451' has an unsupported hash algorithm:10(SHA512).
ERROR  CommonBackend: Could not verify signature for metalink md5sums
ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot authenticate the metalink file, it might be corrupt
```

... but there is no unhandled fatal error which prevents an installation.

If you want to patch an existing wubi.exe it is not necessary to build the whole wubi.exe from source.

If you copy api.py from source (source path: **/src/openpgp/sap/api.py**) to 
your wubi.exe with 7z (destination path: **/lib/openpgp/sap/api.py**) it should work, too.

If you don't want to patch anything, [here](http://bit.ly/1O1AJLz) are also already fixed versions. **wubi14043.exe**, **wubi14043SB.exe** and **wubi1504SB.exe** use an additional api.py . **wubi1510r299.exe** uses a new build from source.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to bypass this problem with Ubuntu 14.04.3 (it works 100%). You can try to run the same method on Kubuntu 14.04.3 (it should work) or analyze changed isolist.ini file (check the comments) and update wubi1510r298.exe accordingly to run newer version.

Here is the instruction (for version 14.04.3):

1. Download **kubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso** into separate directory.
2. Download **wubi14043.exe** (for version 14.04.3) into the same directory.
3. Install 7z.
4. In the directory with wubi14043.exe create a temporary folder:

   mkdir wubi-temp
5. Go to temporary folder:

   cd wubi-temp
6. Extract wubi14043.exe into tmp folder:

   7z x ../wubi14043.exe
7. Edit file data/isolist.ini and replace its content with the content I pasted below.
8. Update your wubi14043.exe with changed isolist.ini:

   7z u ../wubi14043.exe
9. Remove temporary folder:

   cd..
   rd /s wubi-temp
10. Disconnect your computer from the network and run updated wubi14043.exe - it should be able to install Kubuntu from the local ISO now.

---

**Updated isolist.ini:**

```
[DEFAULT]
version=14.04.3
info_file=.disk/info
kernel=casper/vmlinuz
initrd=casper/initrd.lz
files_to_check=casper/filesystem.squashfs
md5sums=md5sum.txt
metalink_md5sums=MD5SUMS-metalink
metalink_md5sums_signature=MD5SUMS-metalink.gpg
size=0
min_iso_size=600000000
max_iso_size=900000000
min_disk_space_mb=5000
min_memory_mb=256
support=http://www.ubuntu.com/support
installation_dir=ubuntu
#NOTE: installation_dir must also be changed in data/wubildr.cfg

[Ubuntu-i386]
arch=i386
name=Ubuntu
packages=ubuntu-desktop
metalink=http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.3/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.metalink
#metalink=http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-beta-desktop-i386.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-i386.metalink
website=http://www.ubuntu.com
ordering=1

[Ubuntu-amd64]
arch=amd64
name=Ubuntu
packages=ubuntu-desktop
#kernel=casper/vmlinuz.efi
metalink=http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.3/ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.metalink
#metalink=http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-beta-desktop-amd64.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.metalink
website=http://www.ubuntu.com
ordering=1

[Ubuntu GNOME-i386]
arch=i386
name=Ubuntu GNOME
packages=ubuntu-gnome-desktop
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04.3/release/ubuntu-gnome-14.04.3-desktop-i386.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-i386.metalink
website=http://www.ubuntugnome.org
ordering=2

[Ubuntu GNOME-amd64]
arch=amd64
name=Ubuntu GNOME
packages=ubuntu-gnome-desktop
#kernel=casper/vmlinuz.efi
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04.3/release/ubuntu-gnome-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.metalink
website=http://www.ubuntugnome.org
ordering=2

[Kubuntu-i386]
arch=i386
name=Kubuntu
packages=kubuntu-desktop
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04.3/release/kubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-i386.metalink
website=http://www.kubuntu.org
ordering=3

[Kubuntu-amd64]
arch=amd64
name=Kubuntu
packages=kubuntu-desktop
#kernel=casper/vmlinuz.efi
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04.3/release/kubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.metalink
website=http://www.kubuntu.org
ordering=3

[Xubuntu-i386]
arch=i386
name=Xubuntu
packages=xubuntu-desktop
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04.3/release/xubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-i386.metalink
website=http://www.xubuntu.org
ordering=4

[Xubuntu-amd64]
arch=amd64
name=Xubuntu
packages=xubuntu-desktop
#kernel=casper/vmlinuz.efi
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/14.04.3/release/xubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.metalink
website=http://www.xubuntu.org
ordering=4

[Mythbuntu-i386]
arch=i386
name=Mythbuntu
packages=ubuntu-standard
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/14.04.3/release/mythbuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-i386.metalink
website=http://www.mythbuntu.org
ordering=5

[Mythbuntu-amd64]
arch=amd64
name=Mythbuntu
packages=ubuntu-standard
#kernel=casper/vmlinuz.efi
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/14.04.3/release/mythbuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.metalink
website=http://www.mythbuntu.org
ordering=5

[Edubuntu-i386]
min_iso_size=1500000000
max_iso_size=3500000000
min_disk_space_mb=10000
min_memory_mb=512
arch=i386
name=Edubuntu
packages=edubuntu-desktop
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04.3/release/edubuntu-14.04.3-dvd-i386.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/dvd/current/trusty-dvd-i386.metalink
website=http://www.edubuntu.org
ordering=6

[Edubuntu-amd64]
min_iso_size=1500000000
max_iso_size=3500000000
min_disk_space_mb=10000
min_memory_mb=512
arch=amd64
name=Edubuntu
packages=edubuntu-desktop
#kernel=casper/vmlinuz.efi
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/14.04.3/release/edubuntu-14.04.3-dvd-amd64.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/dvd/current/trusty-dvd-amd64.metalink
website=http://www.edubuntu.org
ordering=6

[Lubuntu-i386]
arch=i386
name=Lubuntu
packages=lubuntu-desktop
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.3/release/lubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-i386.metalink
website=http://lubuntu.net
ordering=7

[Lubuntu-amd64]
arch=amd64
name=Lubuntu
packages=lubuntu-desktop
#kernel=casper/vmlinuz.efi
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.3/release/lubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.metalink
website=http://lubuntu.net
ordering=7

[Ubuntu Studio-i386]
min_iso_size=1500000000
max_iso_size=3500000000
min_disk_space_mb=10000
min_memory_mb=512
arch=i386
name=Ubuntu Studio
packages=ubuntustudio-desktop
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/14.04.3/release/ubuntustudio-14.04.3-dvd-i386.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/dvd/current/trusty-dvd-i386.metalink
website=http://ubuntustudio.org
ordering=8

[Ubuntu Studio-amd64]
min_iso_size=1500000000
max_iso_size=3500000000
min_disk_space_mb=10000
min_memory_mb=512
arch=amd64
name=Ubuntu Studio
packages=ubuntustudio-desktop
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/14.04.3/release/ubuntustudio-14.04.3-dvd-amd64.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/dvd/current/trusty-dvd-amd64.metalink
website=http://ubuntustudio.org
ordering=8

[Ubuntu MATE-i386]
arch=i386
name=Ubuntu MATE
packages=ubuntu-mate-desktop
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/14.04.3/release/ubuntu-mate-14.04.3-desktop-i386.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-i386.metalink
website=http://ubuntu-mate.org
ordering=9

[Ubuntu MATE-amd64]
arch=amd64
name=Ubuntu MATE
packages=ubuntu-mate-desktop
#kernel=casper/vmlinuz.efi
metalink=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/14.04.3/release/ubuntu-mate-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.metalink
metalink2=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.metalink
website=http://ubuntu-mate.org
ordering=9
```

Comment: Thanks! Luckily Wubi is supposed to make Ubuntu installations easier…

Comment: Unfortunately Wubi has been officially abandoned and apparently is no longer supported even for the older [X]ubuntu versions (which should work properly). Luckily Wubi source code is available so hopefully it will always be possible to patch it and update, even when simple fixes won't suffice.